# Switching Modes in Prolog on the Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, prolog, sicstus-prolog

The Sicstus Prolog manual says to user "| ?- consult(user)." to enter clauses and to "to return to top-level, type ^D.". However, I am using Windows and the manual doesn't have Windows instructions. How can I return to query mode in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many Prolog systems, like SICStus 4, you can enter the fact `end_of_file.` to finish consultation. This fact will not be consulted, it only serves to indicate the end.

(Warning: I am not a frequent user of Wind-ows. That is, I only have rdesktop for such activity.)

Should you ever have the need to define the fact `end_of_file.` in your program, write `end_of_file :- true.` instead.

If you enter `end_of_file.` as a query on the toplevel, many Prolog systems stop. You can circumvent this by entering `true,end_of_file.` instead.

This slightly bizarre behavior is by no means standardized.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but I think ^Z (Ctrl+Z) should play the same role as ^D (Ctrl+D) on Unix.

Comment: I observed that sometimes it is Ctrl+Z and then Enter. On Unix and Mac it is not necessary to presse Enter after the Ctrl-D. This seems to hold in line mode on Windows. Also the line needs to be empty.

Comment: Try `get_code(C).` and type Ctrl-Z with and without Enter. Yes, you have to type Enter to get a result which is `C = 26` on IF/Prolog.